# multiple email accounts (hotmail, yahoo) and facebook handled together

Tags: email, facebook, yahoo

Is there a way to open yahoo, hotmail and facebook together in an outlook style application?
Like pidgin handles now all my messaging, I'd like another application to handle all my emails from one application.

Comment: What do you want to handle from Facebook?. Wall posts?.

Comment: @JavierRivera yes, messaging. If possible other things too...wall posts, etc....am I asking for too much? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thuderbird 13, now in Alfa, supports Facebook messaging, but no Wall or other advanced features. All versions of Thuderbird support Hotmail or Yahoo.

There is a small article about it in [OMG!Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/instant-messaging-comes-to-thunderbird-13-speed-dial-to-firefox-13/).

You can install it from the mozilla-daily ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install thunderbird-trunk
```

But note that this can also upgrade your firefox and that they are daily builds and can be very unstable. Do not install them on production mahines.

Comment: @javier_riviera Daily is as useless as the older versions of thunderbird. It is just simply not working. Thanks anyway.